# amsul datepicker fetch x & y co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using amsul datepicker javscript library.
I want event object for the selected date.
Currently my code is

```
$('#inputDate')
.attr('data-value', "2014-5-14");
DatepickerObject = $('#inputDate').pickadate({
'today' : '',
'close' : '',
'clear' : '',
onOpen : function() {
},
onSet : function() {
},
});
```

I want to get selected object touch positions.For example if I select any date, I want the co-ordinates of the selected date. i.e. x & y. Please help me here.
i.e. if assume any date is selected by default, i want x & y positions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.split` to split a string by a delimiter (a comma in your case) and then get the tokens and use `parseInt` to convert it to a `number` and add it to the array.

```js
var arr = ["2014,11,6","2014,12,6"];
var result = [];
var tokens = null;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  tokens = arr[i].split(',');
  result.push(parseInt(tokens[0], 10)); //first word
  result.push(parseInt(tokens[1], 10) - 1); //2nd
  result.push(parseInt(tokens[2], 10)); //3rd
}
alert(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: Why `var tokens = null;` instead of just `var tokens;`?

Comment: @Phrogz No specific reason except that it has been a habit to clear variables. `var tokens` is better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take it one step at a time. Here's the initial array:

```
var arr = ["2014,11,6","2014,12,6"]
```

First, split the strings on the commas:

```
var components = arr.map(function(s) { return s.split(/,/); }); 
//=> [ [ "2014", "11", "6" ], [ "2014", "12", "6" ] ]
```

Now turn the strings into numbers and decrement the middle one of each triple:

```
var decremented = components.map(function(a) { return [a[0]-0,a[1]-1,a[2]-0]; });
//=> [ [ 2014, 10, 6 ], [ 2014, 11, 6 ] ]
```

Finally, flatten it into one continuous array instead of an array of two arrays:

```
var flattened = [].concat.apply([], decremented);
//=> [ 2014, 10, 6, 2014, 11, 6 ]
```

Comment: What if I have ["2014-01-01T00:00:00","2014-01-01T00:00:00"] & want to get same output.

Comment: @Anand That is not the input data you placed in your question. Google for parsing ISO8601 datetime strings in JavaScript, and if you still cannot figure it out, ask a new question on this site.

Comment: @Mark You rock man !! .. Solution also explains the code .. amazing !!!!! Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Can use `map()` function. Example:

```
var ar = ["2014,11,6","2014,12,6"],
    newArr = [];
ar.map(function(obj){
    var temp = obj.split(',');
    newArr.push(parseInt(temp[0], 10));
    newArr.push(parseInt(temp[1], 10) - 1);
    newArr.push(parseInt(temp[2], 10));
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and in each reduction step:

1. split each string based by a comma using String.split() into three parts,
2. add each part into the final array while subtracting one from the middle part.

```js
var data = ["2014,11,6","2014,12,6"];

var result = data.reduce(function(final, current) {
  var parts = current.split(',');
  final.push(+parts[0], parts[1]-1, +parts[2]);
  return final;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the first answer thats quicker and more clear.

```
var arr = ["2014,11,6","2014,12,6"];
var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.split(",").forEach(function(x){result.push(parseInt(x))});
});
```